# Solspace's Calendar and Relationships

Tags: relationships, solspace, calendar

Here is the situation. I have two channels; one is "calendar_events" and the other one is "projects" and there is a relationship field, "event_related_project" to relate that particular event to a specific project.

```
<h2>{title}</h2>
<h4 class="project_tagline">{project_tagline}</h4>
        {project_description}
            <section class="related-activities">
            <h3 class="related-title">Related Events</h3>
            <ul>
            {parents field="event_related_project" orderby="date" }
                {if parents:no_results}
                <p class="note-message">No related events are found.</p>
                {/if}
                <li><a href="{path='event/view'}/{parents:entry_id}/">{parents:title}</a> / {event_start_date format="%F %d, %Y"}</li>
            {/parents}
            </ul>

            <h3 class="related-title-news">Related News</h3>
            <ul>
            {parents field="news_related_project" orderby="date" limit="3"}
            {if parents:no_results}
            <p class="note-message">No related news are found.</p>
            {/if}
            <li><a href="{title_permalink='news/view'}">{parents:title} / {parents:entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}</a></li>
            {/parents}  
            </ul>
        </section>
```

It can display all the related events under a specific project but I cannot display the "event_start_date". I also tried to make the list wrapped by the {exp:calendar:events} pair tag but the result does not show correctly. May someone help?
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the event_id to an embedded template to a calendar:events tag.
Which you would use to display the date.

something like:

```
{embed="my_date_template" event_id="{parents:entry_id}"}
```

then, your embedded template:

```
{exp:calendar:events event_id="{embed:event_id}"}
{event_start_date format="%F %d, %Y"}
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

Comment: For Calendar 3.1.0, as the parameter of event_id is not available for use, what alternative approach will you suggest for the same result?